# Activate command on TreeViewItem click, VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions, treeviewitem

I would like to run a command on the click of a tree view item, rather than in a menu that comes up. Right now in my package.json, I have this:

```
    {
      "command": "test.view.showError",
      "when": "view == test.view && viewItem == test",
      "group": "inline"
    }
```

Right now, "inline" will put an icon next to the words which you have to click to run the command, but I would like the command to run when I click on the node itself.

What do I change "group" to? Or do I do something different entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the `command` property on the `TreeItem` instance.

> **command?: [Command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#Command)**
>
> The [command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#Command) that should be executed when the tree item is selected.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TreeItem

Comment: what about doubleclick?

Comment: You can / have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Any example would be great

Comment: https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe/blob/master/src/vshaxe/view/dependencies/DependencyTreeView.hx#L226

Answer (score 2):

Pass a `vscode.Command` object to your `TreeItem` like in the snippet below. Make sure you have defined your command in `package.json` and `extension.ts`.

```
class TreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {

    command = {
        "title": "Show error",
        "command": "test.view.showError",
    }
    constructor(label: string) {
        super(label);
    }
}
```

Here's the complete type definition for `vscode.Command`:

```
    /**
     * Represents a reference to a command. Provides a title which
     * will be used to represent a command in the UI and, optionally,
     * an array of arguments which will be passed to the command handler
     * function when invoked.
     */
    export interface Command {
        /**
         * Title of the command, like `save`.
         */
        title: string;

        /**
         * The identifier of the actual command handler.
         * @see [commands.registerCommand](#commands.registerCommand).
         */
        command: string;

        /**
         * A tooltip for the command, when represented in the UI.
         */
        tooltip?: string;

        /**
         * Arguments that the command handler should be
         * invoked with.
         */
        arguments?: any[];
    }
```