# How to log file data onclick on vscode workspace using onDidChangeSelection event

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to get file data on file click on workspace.

For example I have `todo-list` project folder and a file named `app.js`. I want to log `app.js`s' vscode metadata in debug console on file click in tree-view workspace.

> todo-list > app.js

Upon searching in [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView%3CT%3E), I saw `onDidChangeSelection` event. I want to use the event and see if I can log any data on file selection in tree-view.

```
onDidChangeSelection: Event<TreeViewSelectionChangeEvent<T>>
```

Can anyone please help me on how to use `onDidChangeSelection` event? I already tried scanning `vscode.window` and `vscode.TreeItem` and still can't find the event.

And if anyone had already tried logging file data on file click in tree view, what vscode event/api did you use?

Comment: the easy way to handle a click in a view is to register a `command with parameters` in your TreeItem subclass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activate command on TreeViewItem click, VSCode Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525821/activate-command-on-treeviewitem-click-vscode-extension)

Comment: @Gama11 no im trying to make a vscode extension. i want to log file data in debug console by clicking files on workspace

Comment: You can add a context menu item (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382136/can-a-vscode-extension-create-an-explorer-context-menu-for-a-specific-file), but I don't think you can handle left clicks on built-in tree views.